# Scratching my head about the modified dietz method

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency, rate-of-return, portfolio

I'm trying to compute the money weighted rate of return for my crypto investments using the modified dietz method, as I believe this is the golden standard to measure investment.

The formula is [quite simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Dietz_method) (at least if you know a little of math I guess):

[image: mwrr]

where:

- A is the starting market value
- B is the ending market value
- [image: F] is the net external inflow for the period (so contributions to a portfolio are treated as positive flows while withdrawals are negative flows)

Now let's compute the rate of return with the following example:

- I open my account
- I transfer in 100$ and buy 1 BTC
- I sell it at 110$ and transfer the money out
- One year later (or a long time after) I close the account. (**One year later so we can give all transaction a weight of 1 has they were present for the whole period**).

Or in a more readable fashion:

| Time | Action | Market value | Net external inflows (F) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t0 | Open the account, nothing in there | 0 | 0 |
| t1 | Buy 1 BTC @ 100, ie contribute to portfolio +100 | 100 | +100 |
| t2 | Sell 1 BTC @ 110, ie withdraw from portfolio -110 | 0 | +100-110=-10 |

If I want to compute the rate of return with the modified dietz method once the account is closed, I would use the following values:

- A = startig market value = 0
- B = ending market value = 0
- F = (+100 - 110) = -10

Which gives us 10/-10 = -1, while the expected result should be 0.1 (gain of 10%).

I don't understand what am I missing here?

Comment: You should show the ending value *before you withdraw* [or, put another way, show it as the cash portion of your total portfolio, and start with the cash portion of your portfolio as well, meaning you start with 100 already and end at 110]; A = 100 B = 110 F = 0.

Comment: I have no idea why I get down voted. It's a genuine question and I thought I explained well... Not a welcoming community!

Comment: Well you are being a bit condescending to people who are pointing out flaws in your approach. For example even in your question you say "The formula is quite simple (at least if you know a little of math I guess)". That doesn't make people eager to continue to explain your misconceptions.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry if that's the case, english is not my first language and I was actually trying to achieve the opposite, as I thought that stating that the formula is "simple" might not be a feeling shared by others -_-
Anyway I think I figured things out after scratching my head harder, I will post as an answer.

Comment: well yes, that is kind of what makes it condescending - you are implying that you understand the formula better than the people who you are asking for help.

Comment: no, I'm assuming that people fluent in mathematics won't have an issue with the formula, while people who are not might have an issue and I don't want them to feel bad about it. But I understand that it can be understood the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The Modified Dietz method is designed to measure the return of an intermediate period of an existing portfolio. it essentially measures the change in portfolio value (B-A) relative to the starting value (A) accounting for any internal cash flows that may skew the investment return. using a starting value of zero does not fit this paradigm.

If the ending value is zero, the interpretation of that in the method is that your investments have lost all of their value (not that you have "cashed out"). A more realistic application of the Dietz method would be to use 100 as the starting value and 110 as the ending value with no intermediate cash flows. that would give you a 10% return for the simplistic example which obviously fits the data.

Comment: That's not working either. Let's imagine I start at 100 (A) and finish also at 100 (B). In between, I add +100 to buy some BTC that takes value, now it worth 250$ so I decide to sell 150$ (so I finish the perio with 100 in B). Now A=100, B=100 and F=+100-150=-50. The results is 1, while the result should be 0.5

Comment: No, if you start with 100 (the initial cash), then buy/sell bitcoin, no additional cashed is used, so A=100, B=110, and F=0

Comment: So even if you use additional cash that doesn't work:
start at 100, add 100 (now portfolio is 200), then price go up and worth 250$ and I sell for 150$, so at the end of the period I have 100. Now we have A=100, B=100 and F=+100-150=-50 which means that the rate of return is 1. Or maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: The Dietz method is meant to measure the incremental return of an _existing_ portfolio relative to the starting value - you are trying to measure the return of cash that's _added_ to the portfolio which is not a suitable case for the Dietz method. if you treat the initial 100 as the "Starting" value and the 110 as the "ending" value, with no cash added in between, then the Dietz method will fit.

Comment: I think that's exactly the point of the dietz method, being able to measure the rate of return when there are cash flows (that's actually the F part of the equation).

Comment: It's not the cash flow that are the problem - it's the starting balance. The method is designed to measure the growth of the starting balance (A) by using the ending balance (B) and accounting for any cash flows in between. Since you're wanting to measure the growth of the $100 in bitcoin, _that_ needs to be your starting balance.